# how to get the latest records from the table based on the value of the a varchar column

Tags: sql, max

I have a table with the following data. i'm trying to get the latest records from the table based on the value of the a varchar column.

User    Date    Version_No

1   1-Aug-13    5.0.12.23

1   14-Aug-13   2.0.7P

1   20-Aug-13   2.0.8P

2   2-Aug-13    5.0.12.23

2   20-Aug-13   2.0.8P

3   1-Aug-13    2.0.7P

3   14-Aug-13   5.0.12.23

3   20-Aug-13   5.0.12.23

4   20-Aug-13   5.0.12.23

5   14-Aug-13   5.0.12.23

5   20-Aug-13   2.0.8P

Datatype of Version_No column is Varchar.
I want the result to give me the list of users with the version they were running on 20-Aug-13.

User    Date    Version_No

1   20-Aug-13   2.0.8P

2   20-Aug-13   2.0.8P

3   20-Aug-13   5.0.12.23

4   20-Aug-13   5.0.12.23

5   20-Aug-13   2.0.8P

i used max function with the column Version_no but that didn't work as its returning the highest value 5.0.12.23 in most cases.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the latest date for each user:

```
SELECT yt.User, yt.Date, yt.Version_No
FROM (SELECT User, MAX(Date) AS LatestUpdate FROM YourTable GROUP BY User) AS lu
INNER JOIN YourTable AS yt ON lu.LatestUpdate = yt.Date AND lu.User = yt.User
```

Edited based on comment.

Comment: i cant only rely on the date as the filter as different users may have upgraded the application on different dates. so i have to take a date range with the filter to pull the version running on the date the user had last launched the application. hope that helps.

Comment: Adjusted the answer so that it should get the latest date for each user and then join back your table so that you can get what version they are running.  This is assuming the latest date for each user indicates their "current" or "latest" version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select user, date, Version_No from tablename where trunc(date) = '20-AUG-2013'
```

I use trunc to eliminate time as a problem. plus the date format may be off depending on what DB you're using and NLS format.